# How do I view all Git pull requests across repositories in TFS?

Tags: git, tfs, pull-request

I'm managing a team that works in many Git repositories in TFS. We are having a difficult time keeping track of pull requests in TFS. I was hoping to query all repos' pull requests so i could see the status of each. Is there a way to do this within TFS or VS? If not, is there a way to do this with other Git tools?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I needed to get all pull requests from our project across 275-ish repo's. So, I made a little app! [Here's the link to my code on GitHub.](https://github.com/sierpinski/Blitz) It's yours! Hope you find it useful!

Comment: Cool. I'll try it out.

Comment: I wrote it using .net core. If you can't build it out because of that, just grab the controller and views and place them in your preferred MVC app. You might have to install the Newtonsoft JSON nuget package if you move it to .net 4.5, for example.

Comment: Yeah, I'm working through the steps and will let you know what I had to do to get it running.

Comment: @Trevor I converted that app to a [VSTS extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=sierpinski.blitz-allpulls-extension). Might be even more handy for you!

Comment: By the way, I got this running and I love it.

Answer (score 1):

No. And no.

But you could write a program that query [the TFS rest api for pull requests](https://www.visualstudio.com/integrate/api/git/pull-requests) to list them.

You will have to query all the existing projects and for each project, the pull requests and display that.

Ps: using the json newtonsoft library could help you a lot to do that...

Answer (score 1):

From Version 16 your can click on top left icon
[Personal project page icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TCOvv.png)

And this will navigate you to your project info page.
The from the tabs list click on "My pull requests".